# Android button/control with notification indicator (iOS style)

Tags: android, button, notifications, controls

I need a button that displays number of notifications, items, etc. like in the below picture.
I don't want to reinvent the wheel and I'm just wondering if this has been already done or there's a control I can use to replicate the effect.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying, but this is a good feature and i'm not trying to replicate the exact look and feel of iOS, i need a control that will display the number of items associated with it in some shape or form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [github project](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger).
But keep in mind that you shouldn't copy other platforms UI patterns in android apps.